# How to use the 'main' parameter in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, asynchronous

I have done quite some search already. However, still having doubts about the 'main' parameter in the package.json of a Node project.

1. How would filling in this field help? Asking in another way, can I start the module in a different style if this field presents?
2. Can I have more than one script filled into the main parameter? If yes, would they be started as two threads? If no, how can I start two scripts in a module and having them run in parallel?

I know that the second question is quite weird. It is because I have hosted a Node.js application on OpenShift but the application consists of two main components. One being a REST API and one being a notification delivering service.

I am afraid that the notification delivering process would block the REST API if they were implemented as a single thread. However, they have to connect to the same MongoDB cartridge. Moreover, I would like to save one gear if both the components could be serving in the same gear if possible.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

From [the npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main):

> The main field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your
>   program. That is, if your package is named foo, and a user installs
>   it, and then does require("foo"), then your main module's exports
>   object will be returned.
>
> This should be a module ID relative to the root of your package
>   folder.
>
> For most modules, it makes the most sense to have a main script and
>   often not much else.

To put it short:

1. You only need a `main` parameter in your `package.json` if the entry point to your package differs from `index.js` in its root folder. For example, people often put the entry point to `lib/index.js` or `lib/<packagename>.js`, in this case the corresponding script must be described as `main` in `package.json`.
2. You can't have two scripts as `main`, simply because the entry point `require('yourpackagename')` must be defined unambiguously.

Comment: Thanks, then I would consider implementing the component as a child process.

Comment: Side-note 1, `electron` honors the main parameters, i.e. `electron .` does start the right thing from a subfolder, if there's a e.g. a `"main": "dist/app/index.js",` in `package.json` (might hold true for other platforms/frameworks as well).

Comment: Side-note 2: `You can't have two scripts as main...` – true. However, if your package happens to provide for example multiple CLI commands (during development accessible under `./node_modules/.bin/<symlink>`) [check out the "bin" parameter](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin).

Comment: I have build/index.js but if I change it to src/index.js it does do anything. it still pointing to buld/index. I am using npm link

Comment: everyone is using `.js` extensions here, but "module identifiers" don't have extensions.. i dislike the ambiguity about which we're supposed to use

Comment: Instead of require("foo"), how does this work for ES6 imports...e.g in a typical NodeJS/React app

Comment: @testndtv it's all quite similar, e.g. `import Foo from 'foo'` will be looking for a default export in the entry point of the `foo` package, which would be whatever the `main` parameter in the `foo`'s `package.json` is set to (or `index.js` buy default).

Comment: so how do you execute index.js through this 'main' parameter?

Answer (score 69):

To answer your first question, the way you load a module is depending on the module entry point and the main parameter of the *package.json*.

Let's say you have the following file structure:

```
my-npm-module
|-- lib
|   |-- module.js
|-- package.json
```

Without main parameter in the *package.json*, you have to load the module by giving the module entry point: `require('my-npm-module/lib/module.js')`.

If you set the *package.json* main parameter as follows `"main": "lib/module.js"`, you will be able to load the module this way: `require('my-npm-module')`.

Answer (score 38):

If you have for instance in your `package.json` file:

```
{
"name": "zig-zag",
"main": "lib/entry.js",
...
}
```

`lib/entry.js` will be the main entry point to your package.

When calling

```
require('zig-zag');
```

in node, `lib/entry.js` will be the actual file that is required.

Comment: So if the code is not meant to be imported, can we leave out the 'main' parameter?

Comment: @Kokodoko yes that is what is suggested in this case

Answer (score 22):

As far as I know, it's the main entry point to your node package (library) for npm. It's needed if your npm project becomes a node package (library) which can be installed via npm by others.

---

Let's say you have a library with a build/, dist/, or lib/ folder. In this folder, you got the following compiled file for your library:

```
-lib/
--bundle.js
```

Then in your *package.json*, you tell npm how to access the library (node package):

```
{
  "name": "my-library-name",
  "main": "lib/bundle.js",
  ...
}
```

After installing the node package with npm to your JS project, you can import functionalities from your bundled *bundle.js* file:

```
import { add, subtract } from 'my-library-name';
```

---

This holds also true when using [Code Splitting](https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-code-splitting-library) (e.g. Webpack) for your library. For instance, this *webpack.config.js* makes use of code splitting the project into multiple bundles instead of one.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.js',
    add: './src/add.js',
    subtract: './src/subtract.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/lib`,
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: 'my-library-name',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  ...
}
```

Still, you would define one main entry point to your library in your *package.json*:

```
{
  "name": "my-library-name",
  "main": "lib/main.js",
  ...
}
```

Then when using the library, you can import your files from your main entry point:

```
import { add, subtract } from 'my-library-name';
```

However, you can also **bypass** the main entry point from the *package.json* and import the code splitted bundles:

```
import add from 'my-library-name/lib/add';
import subtract from 'my-library-name/lib/subtract';
```

After all, the main property in your *package.json* only points to your main entry point file of your library.

Answer (score 12):

One important function of the `main` key is that it provides the path for your entry point.  This is very helpful when working with `nodemon`.  If you work with `nodemon` and you define the `main` key in your `package.json` as let say `"main": "./src/server/app.js"`, then you can simply crank up the server with typing `nodemon` in the CLI with root as pwd **instead of** `nodemon ./src/server/app.js`.

Answer (score 1):

From the Node.js getting started [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/), it states;

> An extra note: if the filename passed to require is actually a directory, it will first look for package.json in the directory and load the file referenced in the main property. Otherwise, it will look for an index.js.

Answer (score -3):

For OpenShift, you only get one PORT and IP pair to bind to (per application).  It sounds like you should be able to serve both services from a single nodejs instance by adding internal routes for each service endpoint.

I have some info on how OpenShift uses your project's package.json to start your application here: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps#package_json