# How do I connect to Google Storage using Google Functions

Tags: function, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to do a quick automated task of parsing and cleaning data such as:

- When data enters BUCKET1 function is automatically starting
- Data gets parsed, cleaned, ETLed if I may say so,
- Data gets saved to BUCKET2

So I have chose google function triggered by changes in Bucket1, but now I am unable to access files from Bucket1, any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client(project='MyProjectName')

paths = []
all_dfs = []

def hello_gcs(event, context):
    #"""Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    #Args:
    #     event (dict): Event payload.
    #     context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    #"""
    #file = event
    #print(f"Processing file: {file['name']}.")

    for files in glob.glob("gs:/BUCKET1/*/*.csv"):
        paths.append(files)
    print(paths)
    print("testingtesting")
    for i in range(len(paths)):

    temp_list = (paths[i].split("_"))
    date_temp_list = (temp_list[2])
    read_date = (date_temp_list.split("T")[0])

    globals()['table%s' % i] = pd.read_csv('{}' .format(paths[i]), index_col=None, header=0) #create new dfs based on subfolder structure
    globals()['table%s' % i]["Read Date"] = read_date
    all_dfs.append(globals()['table%s' % i])

output_df = pd.concat(all_dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
output_df.to_csv("gs:/BUCKET2/Filename.csv")
```

This code executed locally in Jupyter Notebook works flawlessly, however when executed in Google Functions it does not even load 'paths' (hence I was checking by print(paths) and it returns an empty list. How can I access GS better then?

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense, you are trying to use glob, which is for local filepath expansion, not buckets. You could use the storage client to do a list and then filter for csv files.

If this works locally you probably did additional setup, like using fuse-gcs. But please don't do that, object storage is not file storage and pretending that it is will often lead you into performing very inefficient operations.

Comment: @somethingsomething thanks for your comment! I am still learning, that's why it looks as it does. How can I use the storage client exatly to perform the operations you described? 

On a side note - The whole solution is meant to perform as a go-to single source of truth data lake, hence choice of Google Storage, for lower cost operations

Comment: All of this is basic stuff that can be directly copied from the documentation https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#code-samples and 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python

Comment: can you refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59640287/15774176 is it helpful?