# How to start main index.js from my package.json file

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed node.js and I have created with npm init -f my very first module.

In created package.json file I see "main": "index.js", which should be starting point of my application.
So in same folder I have created this file and I have putted there console.log('test')

The problem is that I don't know how to run it without declaring "scripts": { "start": "node index.js" }

Should I always have scripts section. Because I'm missing why there is entry point of application when I have to use scripts section anyway.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js package.json main parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512992/node-js-package-json-main-parameter)

Comment: Second answer from your link gave me the answer

Comment: Please go through the existing posts solutions related to the problems you are facing before posting the question, it'll help stackoverflow to avoid duplicates of the same kind.

Comment: I did that, I have read documentation from node.js, also checked several topics here in stackoverflow, but I was confused as beginner and I didn't find relevant topic which explain it like I saw it from your link.

Answer (score 33):

Please do read the [Getting Started Guide | Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/). You can start the web server by typing

```
node index.js
```

if you have the `index.js` file specified in `package.json` as follows

```
{
    ....
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    }
    ....
}
```

You can also run the server by the following command

`npm start`

You can read about the difference between `npm start` and `node index.js` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362021/npm-start-vs-node-app-js)