# How to run gulpfile.babel.js(ES6) tasks from subfolder?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs

[image: packages.json]

Works if run from file root folder but on the subfolder, I get a syntax error.

The error is regarding import syntax, failing at first import which is gulp.
If I change to require it works but I need the setup in ES6.
I need to mention again, it works fine if I run the command from a terminal from the folder where gulfile is.

PS: I've updated some babel to 7 - I did not have this problem with babel 6.
Looks like if failing to use .babelrc from the outside root folder.

Everything I could find online.

```
'use strict';
/**
* Note: I updated most of the theme npm deps including gulp@4 
*/
import gulp from 'gulp';
import babel from 'gulp-babel';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify';
import sass from 'gulp-sass'; 
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import autoprefixer from 'gulp-autoprefixer';
import revAll from 'gulp-rev-all';
import cleanCSS from 'gulp-clean-css';
import svgSprite from 'gulp-svg-sprite'; 
import del from 'del';
import merge from 'merge-stream';
import browserify from 'browserify';
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
import buffer from "vinyl-buffer";
import babelify from 'babelify';
```

It should work the same as the task is run from root directory even if is run from the subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should update the `main` parameter of your `package.json` file.

Please refer to [Node.js package.json main parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512992/node-js-package-json-main-parameter) for further info.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope, it works when command is run from the same root folder. But if I go to a subfolder and try to run the command, it fails, giving me the error:  
import gulp from 'gulp';
       ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help.