# Deployment of Express application on Heroku Error : Cannot find module '/app/server.js'

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment

I've been trying to deploy my Express application on Heroku and the build gets created successfully but when I try to open it, I'm greeted with an error message that basically states that the page could not be served.

So, I run `heroku logs --tail` and then I get the following error messages :

[One half of the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ObFW.png)

[Remaining half of the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo9AI.png)

[File Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMn4S.png)

> Procfile

```
web: node server.js
```

> Package.json

```
{
      "name": "conduit-api",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
        "pg": "^8.7.1",
        "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "sequelize": "^6.6.5"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
      }
    }
```

> server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const { sequelize } = require('./src/entities/User/User');
const db = require('./src/config/Database');
const feedRoute = require('./src/routes/Feed/Feed');
const usersRoute = require('./src/routes/Users/Users');
const userRoute = require('./src/routes/User/User');
const articlesRoute = require('./src/routes/Articles/Articles');
const profilesRoute = require('./src/routes/Profiles/Profiles');
const commentsRoute = require('./src/routes/Comments/Comments');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//  Routes

app.use('/api/feed', feedRoute);

app.use('/api/users', usersRoute);

app.use('/api/user', userRoute);

app.use('/api/articles', articlesRoute);

app.use('/api/profiles', profilesRoute);

app.use('/api/articles', commentsRoute);

// REQUESTS

app.get('/', async (req,res) => {
    res.json('Yooooooooooo')
    try {
        await db.authenticate();
        console.log('Connection has been established');
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Error');
    }
})

// To START sequelize and also wipes the DB clean

// async function main() {
//     await sequelize.sync({force: true})
// }

// main()

// TO START sequelize 

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT , () => {
    console.log(`App is listening to ${PORT}`);
})
```

I've tried modifying my procfile and removing and re-installing the modules but the problem still persists.

I've been stuck on this for days now and any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you show the server.js file and whats in it, also where is it situated, in the root directory of the app?

Comment: @Ylama yeaa, I just edited in the server.js file and the code within it. The server.js is also situated in the root directory.

Comment: if you and try run this locally, `npm run start` , same errors ?

Comment: Also you main points to `index.js` , can you show us that file, and also i dont see it being included.

Comment: My bad. Just checked that the main does point to "index.js" and there's no index.js file. So do I replace index.js with server.js?

Comment: yess it looks like thats where your main wil be running from and picking app your express app.

Comment: also have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512992/how-to-use-the-main-parameter-in-package-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you problem is your pointing the main in `package.json` to a file that doesn't exist.

### Package.json

```
"main": "index.js"
```

Your app seems to deploy from you `server.js` file.

The `main` field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your program.
as per documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#main