# main in package.json vs main in webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, package.json, web-frontend

I'm a bit confused about the difference between the `main` entrypoint between package.json and `entry: main` in webpack.config.js when both are present in a project setting. Could someone help me explain the difference between the 2, and at which point of the application do we go into which entrypoint? Which one happens first?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/, https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#main. Not all NPM packages use Webpack.

Comment: Can you explain more? If an npm package uses webpack, will it go first into the `main` entrypoint of package.json and then the one in `webpack`?

Answer (score 1):

`entry: main` is domain specific for Webpack and the term `main` can be replaced by anything. You can call it `monsterkitten`. This is just the name for the entry. `main` just seems to be the [default](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/).

The `main` field in package.json has a meaning and is documented on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512992/how-to-use-the-main-parameter-in-package-json).

The `main` Webpack entry should not collide in any way with the package.json entry.

Comment: Thank you. If the 2 entries aren't colliding, can you walk me through the flow of when a user navigates to your website url, hitting the webapp, then what happens next? What's confusing to me is that I thought it would hit the `main` entrypoint in package.json then it goes to the one in Webpack, but that seems to not be the case based on your explanation

Comment: It is impossible to guess, how you setup your Website. Usually - you have the assets build by Webpack in a folder called "build" (or similar). There you will find your entry chunks compiled by Webpack.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, package.json is for the node backend of the program while Webpack is for the frontend?

Comment: `package.json` is for the dependencies of a Javascript Application/Library. It also provides info, what the Javascript module/library provides for anything depending on it (i.e. the main field). Webpack is an asset bundler, that usually bundles stuff for a frontend.