# How to use the 'main' parameter in package.json in TypeScript project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm trying to create a new NPM package with TypeScript & Node. The package just allows the users to use a data structure I built. I'm trying to figure what is the right entry point (the value of `main`) should be in my `package.json` file. As I understand, I'm going to compile the TypeScript files (which are located in `src/`) into `dist/` directory and those files will be actually hosted in NPM.

So should I have `index.ts` or `index.js`? If it's `index.ts` I'll need to compile it as well right? If it's `index.js`, then I need to point it to `dist/`? I'm a bit confused about what is the "right"/"convention" way to do it. At the end, I just want users to be able to load the classes I export in my `src/mylist.ts` file (which being compiled to `dist/mylist.js`). Do I even need it?

I was reading the [How to use the 'main' parameter in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512992/how-to-use-the-main-parameter-in-package-json) topic, but it only refers to JS project. How should it be in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3):

As typescript is generally compiled before distribution, you should compile it and use `dist/index.js`

You will need this do define what `import {} from 'my-module'` means (i.e. `import {} from 'my-module'` is threated same as `import {} from 'my-module/dist/index.js'`)

If you don't publish your module and are not using it as a dependency of some other your module you don't need this at all, just make a `scripts: { start: "tsx src/index.ts" }` or whatever